# How to achieve a limited number of method executions based on elapsed time?

Tags: flutter, dart, server, frameworks, backend

I would like to know if there is something like a framework for an execution limit per minute.

Let's say I have an API where I can request 100 times per minute.

If I send a "hello world" in a loop, I would exceed that limit.

For example, something like this:

```
ExecutionLimiter executer = ExecutionLimiter(executions: 100, duration: Duration(minutes: 1));

while (true) {
  executer.add(() => print(“hello world“));
}
```

I've found the package [queue](https://pub.dev/packages/queue), but this is only for parallelization.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the support of [Yair Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228673/how-to-achieve-a-limited-number-of-method-executions-based-on-elapsed-time#69228848), I have created a short example program that executes the function n-times in the given time span. The duration of the execution is taken into account.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

List<Instance> instances = [];

int executionLimit = 10;
int apiCallLimitInSeconds = 5;

// for test purposes
int elapsedTime = 0;
int executedFunctions = 0;

main() {
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
    instances.removeWhere((element) => element.isInvalid);

    for (int i = 0; instances.length < executionLimit; i++) {
      instances.add(Instance(
          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: Random().nextInt(100)))
              .then((value) => executedFunctions++)));
    }
    //tests again
    elapsedTime++;
    if (elapsedTime % 5 == 0) {
      print(executedFunctions);
    }
  });
}

class Instance {
  Future<void> execute;
  bool isInvalid = false;

  Instance(this.execute) {
    execute.then((value) => Timer(
        Duration(seconds: apiCallLimitInSeconds), () => isInvalid = true));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timer.periodic to activate a method every given time.

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 600), (Timer t) {
  // Send single api request every 600 ms
});

// Stop sending requests
Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 1), () {
  _timer.cancel();
});
```

Just don't forget to save it in  variable and dispose it when you finish using it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I don't think this works as expected because the average of the number of requests is not taken into account. For example, if 60 requests take 50 seconds to be requested and during the next iteration 60 requests are executed immediately, the average would exceed 100 requests/min.

Comment: Oh I get it. You can calculate yourself how much time should be between each request and use that in the Duration. For example here you can use 1600 milliseconds in the duration and then you won't exceed 100 requests on average. Instead of sending 100 requests in the body of the callback now send just 1 request. I edited the answer to reflect that

Comment: I edited the answer